# What countries have granted emergency powers as a result of Covid-19?

Tags: covid-19, state-of-emergency

What countries have granted emergency powers as a result of COVID-19?

I have recently read the articles linked below regarding emergency powers granted as a result of Coronavirus, but I have been unable to find a list of the countries which have deemed coronavirus an emergency worthy of emergency powers.

https://www.politico.com/news/2020/03/01/coronavirus-azar-war-powers-medical-supplies-118392

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2020/03/18/coronavirus-what-defense-production-act-trump-has-invoked/2865598001/

https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2020-04-10/cambodia-adopts-law-to-allow-for-emergency-powers-to-tackle-coronavirus

https://www.businessinsider.com/countries-where-coronavirus-emergency-responses-could-be-abused-2020-4#1-hungary-1

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE! I think this needs to be split up into two separate questions, one asking which countries have granted emergency powers, and one asking what the difference is between emergency powers and war powers. (That second question might also be too broad, as each country's emergency and war powers are going to be slightly different.)

Comment: The Defense Production Act might be *considered* a war power but it is explicitly not solely a war power.

Comment: [State of emergency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_emergency#Active_in_2020) might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things tend to be pretty out of date given the rapidly evolving situation, but Frontex [put out](https://frontex.europa.eu/media-centre/news-release/covid-19-restrictions-4IdY3J) an EU map like that some weeks ago (March 26)

[image]

By March 17 almost all US states (48) had [declared](https://www.businessinsider.com/california-washington-state-of-emergency-coronavirus-what-it-means-2020-3) some sort of emergency related to Covid-19, so a US map like that would a little superfluous unless more detailed as to what the measures were (how they differ), and insofar I haven't found something like that.